# What does "Invalid type 't' in unpack" mean?

Tags: perl

This line of code errors out with "Invalid type 't' in unpack":

```
my $x = unpack(chr(ord("a") + 19 + print ""), $string);
```

It is trying to retrieve the original value of $x that was first transformed this way:

```
my $string = pack("u",$x);
```

I can't find this error anywhere on the internet.  I am basically trying to make a simple string obfuscator, that can retrieve the original string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function `print` returns false on failure.  In numerical context, false values are considered as 0.  In your case, the first argument of pack becomes "t" and Perl raises an error.

Note that `print` can be failed, typically in case when you did `close STDOUT`. In addition, `print` returns **true** on success, not limited to `1`. There is little possibility of returning `2`, `blah`, or any other true values on future versions.

Comment: When you said "the first argument of pack becomes 't'" it dawned on me.  I was one off... I needed to make it a +20 if I was packing with a "u".

Answer (score 5):

Why in the world would you do this? Why are you using print for its value? The inverse operation to `$string = pack("u", $x);` is simply `$x = unpack("u", $string);`

Comment: A teeny bit of obfuscation which clearly even had me fooled.  I am implementing a requirement that doesn't make much sense to implement, beyond resulting in a paycheck.  :)

Answer (score 1):

diagnostics is there to explain it :)

```
$ perl -Mdiagnostics -le " print unpack q{t} , 1"
Invalid type 't' in unpack at -e line 1 (#1)
    (F) The given character is not a valid pack or unpack type.
    See "pack" in perlfunc.
    (W) The given character is not a valid pack or unpack type but used to be
    silently ignored.

Uncaught exception from user code:
        Invalid type 't' in unpack at -e line 1.
 at -e line 1.
```